# Unknown command 'rails-console' in vmc

Tags: vmc

vmc works well except "rails-console" command is unknown. my vmc version is 0.4.7 and os is mac 10.7.5. But it seems this command should be supported. Do you know why rails-console doesn't work for my environment?

Comment: This question is  "why vmc version 0.4.7" does not support rails-console command ?", because everywhere vmc rails-console <app_name> command is mentioned.

Comment: did you find a newer version of vmc that still supports rails-console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uninstall vmc version 0.4.7 by the following command

```
 gem uninstall vmc -v 0.4.7
```

Then install vmc version 0.3.21 and caldecott gem.

```
gem install vmc -v 0.3.21
gem install caldecott
```

Try running the following command:-

```
vmc rails-console application_name
```

It worked for me.

Comment: As your suggestion, it means only 0.3.21 pre version supports rails-console command?